# SSRS - avg function by subtotals

Tags: reporting-services

I have details, subtotals and totals.

When I put avg function in totals line I have avg of every row.

I need avg of subtotals

How to do it?

week1
        day1.....     2
        day3.....        3
        day4.....     4
        day6.....        2
        total....       11  sum()
week2
        day1.....        3
        day2.....        2
        total.....       5  sum()
Total
...........                    16   sum()   OK
............                      2,66666   avg() here should be (11+5)/2   =8

[Result after implementing solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujjrV.png)

Comment: What you did till now? Show your code and effort.

Comment: so far: 
=Avg(Fields!KosztyRazem.Value) returns avg from all fields 

=Avg(sum(Fields!KosztyRazem.Value)) in the Total Field  - 

tried also 


=ReportItems!TextBox245.Value   ( texbox where subtotals are) - error

and have no other ideas

Comment: Update your question with your code by edit it. Don't let such information in comments. You have better chances that somebody will help you.

Comment: Can you post some example data and what you expect for the results?

Comment: i have  edited main post and added example

Answer (score 0):

I created a dataset to replicate your sample data as follows:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (week int, day int, amount int) 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 1, 2), 
(1, 3, 3), 
(1, 4, 4), 
(1, 6, 2), 
(2, 1, 3), 
(2, 2, 2)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then built a simple tablix as you had done (more or less)

I included the incorrect results you had for illustration and then added a new expression to calculate this correctly.

The result looks like this

[image]

You can ignore the other datasets, this is just a report I use for testing. Only dataset3 is used here.

The expression used was this

```
=Sum(Fields!amount.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!week.Value)
```

You'll just need to edit this to match your field names. It basically just sums all the detail amounts then divides by the number of distinct weeks in the dataset.

Comment: almost working. If emty week then is not counted but should be counted as 0.    Example in main  post in the link:  Result after implementing solution

Comment: If you have an empty week it will still have to be in your dataset. If you have a date table then join to that so you return 0 or null values in your datasets for the empty weeks. If you can't do this then you would have to get the max week number subtract the min week number and use that to divide by. If the week 'number' are not real number though you would need to strip out the bit that isn't the week number first.

Comment: Resolved:  =sum(Fields!KosztyRazem.Value)/countdistinct(Fields!Tydzien.Value,"Tablix3").    Add at the end parametr - name of tablix

Comment: Great. If you find my answer useful then please upvote it or if you think it answered your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: It was helpful. I have tried to vote but is message that i have not enough reputation yet and is recorded but not published